# How to access classes in java

Tags: java, class

I have a class file named **User.class** in `D:/classes/directory` and i used

`Class clz=Class.forName("D:/classes/User")`

But it throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` can anybody tell me how can i resolve this problem.

Comment: This can be helpful: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-load-a-class-that-is-not-on-the-classpath.html

Answer (score 2):

`Class.forName(className)` expects class to be in classpath and you can give fully qualified class name there

**Note** : className

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the fully qualified name of the class, which includes its package. This is then typically used to look in the classpath, with directories corresponding to package parts. In your case, if the classpath includes `D:\classes` and the class `User` is in the package `directory`, this would work: `Class.forName("directory.User");`

Comment: can you please tell me how can i include D:\classes to the classpath

Comment: @elvisanandkumar: that depends on how your program is started. If it's run via the commandline java tool, add -cp "D:\classes" to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

forName requires the package path. What package do you want User to belong to? Here is an excellent example I found after a little bit of googling: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-does-classforname-method-do/17

Answer (score 0):

try Class.forName("User") but note that you should call it from same directory OR add to classpath your User.class also check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)
if you using packages then try to add Class.forName("com.example.User")